# Conversion between different eDSLs (different type class constraints)

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to "compile" a simple eDSL to the [Atom](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/atom) language. A problem that arises here  is, that the type class constraints on my types/functions do not match those of the Atom language.

One eDSL which compiles to Atom is [copilot](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/copilot), which also has this very same problem an solves it in a rather verbose way. What follows is a simplified version of the involved datatypes:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Type a where   
    TFloat :: Type Float

data Op1 a b where
    Neg :: Type a -> Op1 a a

class NumE a where
instance NumE Float

data Exp e where
    ENeg :: NumE a => Exp a -> Exp a
```

`Type` and `Op1` are part of the new eDSL, `NumE` and `Exp` belong to the compilation target. To convert between the eDSLs at some point I need a function `op2exp` with the following type:

```
op2exp :: Op1 a b -> Exp a -> Exp b
```

Now the way Atom handles this is [rather](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/copilot-c99/2.1.1/doc/html/src/Copilot-Compile-C99-Witness.html) [verbose](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/copilot-c99/2.1.1/doc/html/src/Copilot-Compile-C99-C2A.html):

```
data NumEInst e = NumE e => NumEInst

numEInst :: Type a -> NumEInst a
numEInst TFloat = NumEInst

op2exp :: Op1 a b -> Exp a -> Exp b
op2exp op = case op of
    Neg t -> case numEInst t of NumEInst -> ENeg
```

This works, but is quite cumbersome and full of repetition.

**Question:**

Is there a way, maybing using new language features, to write the `op2exp` function in an easier way? Ideally something along the lines of:

```
op2exp (Neg t) = ENeg
```

Ideally, I wouldn't even need the `Type` data type and have the compiler figure out that all the types match.

Comment: Your ideal implementation compiles for me in GHC 7.6.1

Comment: Oh, you're right. The argument of `Neg` should be a variable of course. I changed the question. If you try to compile this, you'll get an error like: `Could not deduce (NumE b) arising from a use of ENeg`, which is exactly the problem this `NumEInst` solves.

Comment: Can't you just replace `Type a ->` with `NumE a =>` in the `Neg` constructor?

Comment: I'd like not to, since maybe in the future I might want to compile to a different eDSL (i.e. [ivory](https://github.com/GaloisInc/ivory) looks interesting), like copilot does with [svb](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sbv) and Atom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the `Op1` datatype parametric in the target language, by using a type parameter of kind `* -> Constraint`. Looking at the Atom and Ivory libraries, I think something like this should work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, ConstraintKinds #-}

data Op1 expr a b where
    Neg :: (expr a, Num a) => Op1 expr a a

class AtomExpr a where
instance AtomExpr Float

data AtomExp e where
    ENeg :: (AtomExpr a, Num a) => AtomExp a -> AtomExp a

op2exp :: Op1 AtomExpr a b -> AtomExp a -> AtomExp b
op2exp Neg = ENeg
```